# angular order by date working as a string

Tags: angularjs

Please look at following code, it is working fine for order-by date but as a string.

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in nonDeletedItems(this) | orderBy: 'data.FollowUpDate'" 
mp-managed-list-item item="i" ready="isReady" item-template="rowTemplate" 
item-template-html="rowTemplateHtml" item-list-type="listType"></tr>
```

I need to order by date as date.

Comment: It would only work if `data.FollowUpDate` has date object..

Comment: data.FollowUpDate is string like "01/01/2016" . can we convert it into date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom filter to achive this.

```
myApp.filter('sortByDate', function () {
    return function (events) {
        if (!events) {
            return true;
        }
        if (events.length == 0) {
            return events;
        }
        for(var i=0; i<events.length; i++){
            for(var j=i+1; j<events.length; j++){
                var t1 = new Date(events[i].updatedTime).getTime()
                var t2 = new Date(events[j].updatedTime).getTime()
                if(t1 > t2){
                    var temp = events[i]
                    events[i] = events[j]
                    events[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return events;
    };
})
```

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in nonDeletedItems(this) | sortByDate" 
  mp-managed-list-item item="i" ready="isReady" item-template="rowTemplate" 
  item-template-html="rowTemplateHtml" item-list-type="listType">
</tr>
```

Comment: yes, it is working fine but got descending mode. can you please change it with ascending mode ?

Comment: Updated for ascending order.